# How to clear the console/trace?

Tags: air

The following JavaScript code writes a line to the console when using ADL:

```
air.trace("Hello world!");
```

But the console can soon fill up when tracing a lot of data.

How can I clear the console?

I've tried Googling with no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've ended up doing:

```
function clearDebug()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < 56; i++)
        air.trace();
}
```

If anyone has a "standard" way of doing this, feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it!

Failing that though, this works (though you may have to edit `56` to a number of console lines suitable to your screen resolution).